# convert cakephp configuration file nodejs configuration file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Currently my project is built in cakephp 2. I am moving stuffs to node.js from cakephp. I have a piece of code in core.php file. My core.php file includes these piece of code:

```
$bucket = env('PRJECTNAME_S3_BUCKET');
$imgPath = env('BASE_PATH_IMG');

Configure::write('Files.S3Bucket', $bucket);

if (!empty($imgPath)) {
    Configure::write('Files.url', $imgPath);
} else if (empty($bucket)) {
    if (!empty($httpHost)) {
        $s = null;
        if (env('HTTPS')) {
            $s = 's';
        }
        $httpHost = 'http' . $s . '://' . $httpHost;
    }
    Configure::write('Files.url', $httpHost);
} else {
    Configure::write('Files.url', 'https://s3.eu-central-2.amazonaws.com/' . $bucket);
}
$filespath = Configure::read('Files.url');
if (substr($filespath, 0, strlen('http://localhost')) == 'http://localhost') {
    Configure::write('Files.safeurl', '');
} else {
    Configure::write('Files.safeurl', $filespath);
}
```

Whenever I need to use the path for image I used to invoke it `Configure::read('Files.url')` in this way.
As a said I am moving our code to node.js from cakephp. I need to write these piece of code in node.js.
Can anyone help me out to converting this cakephp code to node.js?

Comment: That code is quite convoluted, but ultimately it’s just setting some constants - why not expect BASE_PATH_IMG etc. to be defined and just define them?

Comment: I realize you're migrating away from this app (and that it's an obsolete version of CakePHP) but for reference and any future readers that's duplicating the standard config setting for [App.imageBaseUrl](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.10.24/app/Config/core.php#L130-L134).